# Oracle: date type giving errors

Tags: oracle, variables, date, plsql, date-conversion

```
if day < 10 then
  dataV := to_date(((day*1000000) + (month*10000) + year),'d/mm/yyyy');
else
  dataV := to_date(((day*1000000) + (month*10000) + year),'dd/mm/yyyy');
end if;
```

Guys I'm trying to form a date using only integers by doing this math as I saw in some Oracle forum but it keeps giving me errors because apparently this isn't correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show an example of the values?

Comment: In this case I'm trying to create this date '1/01/2014'.

Comment: `to_date()` takes a *character* value as it's input, not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, one of the following examples should help:

```
day:= 1;
month:=1;
year:=2014;
if day < 10 then
  dataV := to_date(((day*1000000) + (month*10000) + year),'dmmyyyy');
else
  dataV := to_date(((day*1000000) + (month*10000) + year),'ddmmyyyy');
end if;
```

Or

```
day:= 1000000;
month:= 10000;
year:=2014;
if day < 10 then
  dataV := to_date(day + month + year,'dmmyyyy');
else
  dataV := to_date(day + month + year,'ddmmyyyy');
end if;
```

Comment: The error it gives me is "literal doesn't match the date format". And I tried your code, it says the month is invalid for some reason.

Comment: Can you show the exact values of day, month, year? Or maybe the value of the next expression? ((day*10000) + (month*1000) + year)

Comment: Day = 10000
Month = 1000
Year = 2014

Comment: The Day should be 1 the month 1 and the year 2014, if you would like to use this expression. If you adhere to your input examples then you should remove the constant multiplications. (to_date(day+month+year,...)

Comment: Can you give me the code ? I'm trying so many different ways and every single one is wrong. So annoying this.

Comment: I modified my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Ehh sorry. I thing there wasn't enough zeros... I adjusted it.

Comment: It works except it says that enters in conflict with the julian date. Do you know what is this?

Comment: I am not familiar with this message. Maybe this helps: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58312/newch227.htm